# static ip on debian and nm-applet doesn't show the networks at the reboot

Tags: linux, networking, connection, debian

I m trying to use static ip address on debian. I followed a tutorial and I modified the /etc/networking/interfaces but every time I reboot I can't do anything because the nm-applet says that I have select a manually connection.. I'm on Debian

Answer (score 0):

The file you need to modify is `/etc/network/interfaces` and not `/etc/networking/interfaces`.
Could you post what you have in this `ìnterfaces` file to see if it is complete?
(you need to have the `iface eth0 inet static` line or similar and the configuration for the the interface (like IP, gateway, dns info)